# Error while installing chatterbot. I don't know what packages to install to solve the error

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, chatbot, chatterbot

I am using windows 10 64-bit
I am using python 3.8 64 bit 
my system has microsoft visual c++ 2013 redistributable(x86 and x64)
microsoft visual c++ 2015-2019 redistributable (x86 and x64)
visual studio build tools 2019
I don't know to solve the problem. Please help
i have tried pip install --upgrade setuptools
and pip install --upgrade chatterbot also

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.292]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\win10>pip install ChatterBot
Collecting ChatterBot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
  Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2
  Using cached nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (63 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-46.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (582 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.16-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.18.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (12.8 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.45.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for blis: started
      Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9fke1se7\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9fke1se7\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3b4oyob4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay\Include\blis'
           cwd: C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fke1se7\blis\
      Complete output (26 lines):
      BLIS_COMPILER? None
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc
      {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
      clang -c C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fke1se7\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsuq10hhw\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9fke1se7\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9fke1se7\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9fke1se7\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3b4oyob4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay\Include\blis' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\win10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-10eop7rd\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\win10>
```

Comment: Try downloading and installting `blis` as a whl file. You can find it [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tried what you said but still there is same error

Comment: Did the installation if the whl file go succesfully? It sounds odd that the chatterbot install would still try to install blis after a succesful instal with the blis whl

Comment: yes it was successful@FlyingTeller there is no error again of wheel package not found but the blis is showing the same error

Comment: Ah, I rechecked and found the problem. Chatterbot requires blis<0.3 and the whl i pointed you to is too new

Answer (score 1):

`chatterbot` requires spacy 2.1.9 which requires `blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1`. Checking on `pypi`, only 0.2.4 seems to match these requirements. For this version, only the source package is [available](https://pypi.org/project/blis/0.2.4/#files) when using python 3.8. The whl files only go up to 3.7, which already creates a first option for you: installing python 3.7 instead

If you want to use python 3.8 and use `chatterbot`, you will need to compile `blis` from source. Looking at your error, it is trying to run `clang`. The project description on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/blis/0.2.4/#description) state that:

> If you want to install from source and you’re on Windows, you’ll need to install LLVM

So you will need to install the LLVM compilersuite to get the source installation running.

Comment: Which of the two recommendations. Did you install a lower python version or did you end up getting the source installation running? Also, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: lower python version @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 1):

did you tried upgragding your `setuptool`?

```sh
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

On my system with the latest chatterbot only worked with `Python 3.7.9 x64`.
I'm using **VENV** to switch between Python versions