# how to fix the error while installing chatterBot?

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am trying to install the chatterBot . But i had tried many times but it is showing error to me . What's the problem with this.I had already upgraded pip too . But problem is not fixed.Also I am using python 3.9 version .Given below is the error. Every time it shows error to me.

```
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.7 MB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
  Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached Pint-0.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (205 kB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3
  Using cached pymongo-3.11.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (383 kB)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (129 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-53.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.56.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (177 kB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.7 MB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, blis
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gakvgata'
         cwd: C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j36xkn0g\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
    running build_ext
    building 'preshed.maps' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
    maps.cpp
    preshed/maps.cpp(5728): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(5740): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(5749): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(5755): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(5761): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(5767): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    preshed/maps.cpp(6129): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    preshed/maps.cpp(6145): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for preshed
    Running setup.py clean for preshed
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\blis_51c704e8ec224630b296a8818036302f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\blis_51c704e8ec224630b296a8818036302f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q3_oc6p3'
         cwd: C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j36xkn0g\blis_51c704e8ec224630b296a8818036302f\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    msvc
    py_compiler msvc
    {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
    clang -c C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j36xkn0g\blis_51c704e8ec224630b296a8818036302f\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo1flo0wn\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j36xkn0g\blis_51c704e8ec224630b296a8818036302f\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64 
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build preshed blis
  Installing collected packages: numpy, cymem, wasabi, tqdm, srsly, preshed, plac, murmurhash, blis, wheel, thinc, setuptools, Cython
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xptk2d23\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay\Include\preshed'
           cwd: C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j36xkn0g\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\        
      Complete output (9 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'preshed.maps' extension
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
      maps.cpp
      c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'preshed/maps.cpp': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\upadh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j36xkn0g\\preshed_e8db7d3ababc46df99aeac4d0b30ddce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xptk2d23\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay\Include\preshed' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/e2/46650d03c7ff2b57ed7af211d41c3f606540f7adea92b5af65fcf9f605c0/spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz#sha256=62f4a9ddb9a8074d1669db85850738d76fbb1184404c191eb6e8f0dde888d4e2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/spacy/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\upadh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4im3wori\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me to get rid out of this problem.

Comment: `ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis` -> `The system cannot find the file specified msvc` -> `c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'preshed/maps.cpp': No such file or directory`

Comment: No `msvc` command in your system

Comment: similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264547/error-while-installing-chatterbot-i-dont-know-what-packages-to-install-to-solv